# xlog - know if two databases came from the source

Tags: postgresql

I have xlog questions that I'm not sure about.

1)  I have two servers that were once slaves.  How can I know if they were slaves of the same master?  Is it possible to check if they were split from the same source in the past?  I know pg_rewind knows how to check if, but is it possible to easily check it without running pg_rewind in dry run mode?

2)  Is it true that if pg_last_xlog_replay_location is empty this server was never a slave?

3)  Is it possible to know from the database itself to which master the slave is connected?  I know to get this info from the recovery.conf or from the process attributes, but is it written in some system tables as well?

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **were slaves of the same master**

indirectly. you can compare `select xmin,ctid,oid, datname from pg_database`. of course dropping and creating postgres and template databases will change those, so this is very unreliable. but if you check those and find that ALL identifiers match - there's a good change that databases have same source.

more reliable and [sophisticated method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-replication.html) is comparing history file. Eg - if both ex slaves have same timeline, eg in case below 4:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -d 'dbname=replication replication=true sslmode=require' -U replica -h 1.1.1.1 -c 'IDENTIFY_SYSTEM'
Password for user replica:
      systemid       | timeline |   xlogpos
---------------------+----------+--------------
 9999384298900975599 |        4 | F79/275B2328
(1 row)
```

you can check timelines history:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -d 'dbname=replication replication=true sslmode=require' -U replica -h 1.1.1.1 -c 'TIMELINE_HISTORY 4'
Password for user replica:
     filename     |                       content
------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 00000004.history | 1       9E/C3000090     no recovery target specified+
                  |                                                     +
                  | 2       C1/5A000090     no recovery target specified+
                  |                                                     +
                  | 3       A52/DB2F98B8    no recovery target specified+
                  |
(1 row)
```

If both servers have same timeline and same xlog position at which a timeline was created, you can say with much reliability, I believe, that came from same sourse.

2. **empty `pg_last_xlog_replay_location`**

I would say so. It was never a slave and was never recovered from WALs. At least I don't know how to reset `pg_last_xlog_replay_location` on promoted master...

3. **system tables to tell to which master the slave is connected**

Nothing suitable comes to my mind. If you are SU then you can read `recovery.conf` even without shell access, if you're not, you probably would not be able to select such a view...